# Tensorflow: why is multiplication 20x faster than subtraction in this case

Tags: tensorflow

As in title, why is multiplication much faster than subtraction in this example?

In this example we have M=784 inputs and N=100 outputs, so matrix multiplication requires MxN scalar multiplications and (M-1)xN additions, while subtraction requires only MxN scalar subtractions.

Is it because software and hardware is heavily optimized towards multiplication and addition?

Or is it because of all the shape brodcasting that is done here and tensorflow is possibly inefficient at that?

All the computation is done on CPU, so this might be another lead.

Code is as following:

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[784, 100], mean=0., stddev=.5))

sub = tf.expand_dims(input, axis=2)-tf.expand_dims(W1, axis=0)
mul = tf.matmul(input*W)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

start = timer()
sess.run(diff, {input: somedata}) #somedata has shape (100, 784)
timer() - start #yields around 0.15s after averaging multiple tries

start = timer()
sess.run(mul, {input: somedata})
timer() - start #yields around 0.008s after averaging
```

Comment: I think you are mostly timing the overhead of sess.run and not the actual multiplication time.

Comment: Maybe, but still, multiplication is 20 times faster.

Comment: I don't think you can conclude anything meaningful from this benchmark experiment. One thing I noticed is that the subtraction one has two extra ops it has to do because of the expand_dims.